# How to reset a session scoped jsp:useBean?

Tags: jsp, jstl, treemap, usebean

I am creating a `TreeMap` bean. I want to pass this around in the session scope. However, I need to reset/clear this `TreeMap` bean.

This is how I am declaring my bean:

```
<jsp:useBean id="foo" class="java.util.TreeMap" scope="session"/>
```

Any ideas on how to clear/reset the usebean (and keep using the same id) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use 
`c:set` JSTL tag and pass in `null`, the variable will be removed. Another way to remove it to use `c:remove`

So

```
<c:remove var="foo" scope="session"/>
```

or

```
<c:set var="foo" scope="session" value="nullVar"/>
```

where `nullVar` evaluates to `null`